# ¿Como importar y exportar Tablas pivote con LaravelExcel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el Modelo `Persona` y el Modelo `Inmueble`, y estos tienen una relación muchos a muchos entre si, la tabla pivote que trabaja esta relación es `inmuebles_personas` (cabe resaltar que esta relacion no tiene modelo ni controlador, y la lleno mediante el metodo attach), necesito exportar esta tabla, trabajo con Laravel Excel, pero al no tener modelo de esta tabla, no se como trabajar su exportacion e importacion.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el Facade **DB** y su método **table**, no lo he probado pero devuelve también una colección :

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use DB;

class InmueblesPersonasExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;

    public function collection()
    {
        return DB::table('inmuebles_personas')->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Y como lo harías para importar?